# flex-wrap space between rows or columns

Tags: css

Suppose you have a `<div>` with the following CSS:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
```

Notice that there is a fixed `height`. But suppose any child `<div>`s have a `height` of only `50px`.

When these children wrap, the rows are evenly distributed vertically to fill the fixed height of the parent. This can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/lukesawczak/pen/WNKmePp?editors=0110). In that example, the two rows that result from wrapping each gain an equal space under them, such that each row and its space takes up half of the parent's height. But if there are more rows, the height will be redistributed evenly, such that they each take up `(1/n_rows)%`. Of course, a picture is worth 10<sup>3</sup> words...

[image: flex-wrap]

**Goal:** Be able to fix the amount of space between rows. (As I dynamically add items I want the rows to fill in bit by bit without each new row causing the others to shift upwards.)

I haven't found a way to do this. It's not related to item height, margin, or padding, or to the flex gap. References on flex-wrap do not seem to mention this space and I have had no luck with Google. Of course I could just remove the parent's fixed height, but I'd rather not, because then items under the parent will shift as it grows instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for `align-content: flex-start`.